# How to create folder in box?

Tags: android, box

I want to create Folder in my box.I can delete,upload and download files but i don't know how to create new Folder.
I am using this code for uploading file from sdcard,

```
 BoxFileUploadRequestObject upload=BoxFileUploadRequestObject.uploadFileRequestObject(folderId, file.getName(), inputStream);
 BoxAndroidFile f= (BoxAndroidFile) getClient().getFilesManager().uploadFile(upload);
```

Answer (score 0):

ok. i have done it my self after sorting the box API.
Code to create folder is,

```
 BoxFolderRequestObject upload = BoxFolderRequestObject.createFolderRequestObject("new folder", "parent_id");
  BoxAndroidFolder f= (BoxAndroidFolder) getClient().getFoldersManager().createFolder(upload);
```